# Drop Down Lists in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

Hi I am trying to make a drop down list for a group of products, and I want the drop down list to be populated from a list of Products I have stored in a PostgreSQL database. I was wondering if this is possible or if I have to manually populate it myself.

Comment: http://www.designmagick.com/article/10/ will get you started, perhaps on getting data from the database.  Then use that data in your drop down.

Comment: @Marvo I have no problem getting the data from the database, I just don't know how to add it to a drop down list.

Comment: What you want is to generate the HTML of a `<select>` element and its `<option>`s. No, there's no built-in function in PHP to do that. You'll have to cobble it together yourself using loops, like for any other HTML you output using PHP.

Comment: If you have no problem getting the data from the database, then consider rewriting your question to be very specific about what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function may help fetching your db row and eventually use a while loop to populate your menu: https://www.php.net/pg_fetch_row

Following code should do the the trick

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) { echo "product:" . $row[0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a select tag, loop through the array of data, echo it out as options to the select element, end the loop, and then close the select. Not too difficult

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this sample written with php and mysql:

```
<select>
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
?>
        <option value="<?=$row["id"]; ?>"><?=$row["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

**Edit:**

Confused with the tags. Corrected.

Comment: It should be `option` TAG inside the loop, also consider to not give working example, and try to force user to think and do something by himself.

Comment: Also he uses `Postgres` not `MySql` :)

Comment: If you look at my first sentence, I told him that this is gonna be a sample using php & mysql :)